# Splitting a column into multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below :

```
|  A       |  Value |
+----------+--------+
|ABC001035 |  34    |
|USN001185 |  45    |
|UCT010.75 |  23    |
|ATC001070 |  21    |  
+----------+--------+
```

I want to split the column in A (based on last three digits in A) into columns X and Y, and it should look like below

```
|  A       |  Value |    X    | Y   |
+----------+--------+---------+-----+
|ABC001035 |  34    |  ABC001 | 035 |
|USN001185 |  45    |  USN001 | 185 |
|UCT010.75 |  23    |  UCT01  | 0.75|
|ATC001070 |  21    |  ATC001 | 070 |
+----------+--------+---------+-----+
```

So how to split the column A ?

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting? Is it always the last three digits of column A?

Comment: Yes, it's the last three digits of column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index all strings in a series with the [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor:

```
>>> df['X'] = df['A'].str[:-3]
>>> df['Y'] = df['A'].str[-3:]
>>> df
           A  Value       X    Y
0  ABC001035   34.0  ABC001  035
1  USN001185   45.0  USN001  185
2  UCT010.75   23.0  UCT010  .75
3  ATC001070   21.0  ATC001  070
```

Comment: Short is better. take this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split your problem into smaller ones, easier to solve! :)

How to split a string (take the last 3 characters):

```
'Hello world!'[-3:0]
# Returns: ld!
```

How to apply a function over a DataFrame value?

```
df.A.apply(lambda x: x[-3:])
# Returns pandas.Series: [035, 185, 0.75, 070]
```

How to save a Series to a new DataFrame column?

```
# Create Y column.
df['Y'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: x[-3:])
```